# Using VSTS Release Definition to run Entity Framework Code Database Migration

Tags: azure, entity-framework-migrations, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am writing a .NET Core and Entity Framework Core Application using Code-First Migrations.

I want to be able to deploy it to an Azure Web App using Visual Studio Team Services Build and Release Definitions

I want to be able to run the Database Migration as part of the Release Definition using the script

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I've done this via a Command Prompt action in the Release Definition

However I always get the message

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

I've tried making sure that this command is running in the same directory as a .cproj file

I've also tried running a

```
dotnet restore
```

as a previous command prompt task, and this gives an error

```
The folder 'C:\a\r1\a\Drop\s\src\xxxxx' does not contain a project to restore even though it does.
```

Has anybody tried to do a Code First Migration as part of a Team Services Release Definition step?

My other option was to run the migration as part of the Web Application itself but I wanted to run it via the Release process rather than run it in the Application.

Comment: What's the result after you changing to Hosted VS2017 agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **Hosted VS2017** agent instead of **Hosted** agent. My steps:

1. Edit csproj file to add this code below and check in changes (Refer to [.NET Command Line Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) article)

Code:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

2. **Command line** step/task (Tool: `dotnet`; Arguments: `--version`)
3. **Command line** step/task (Tool: `dotnet`; Arguments: `restore`)
4. **Command line** step/task (Tool: `dotnet`; Arguments: `ef --version`)
5. Queue build with **Hosted VS2017** agent.

Comment: In VSTS I have a Build Definition which gets the code from TFS, restores packages and builds and runs a 'dotnet publish'. I wanted the Build step to not be environment specific. I already have Hosted VS2017 for the Build Step. I then wanted the Release Definition to be environment specific and run the migration there. Unfortunately I can't see a way of connecting to Hosted VS2017 for the Release step. WHen I try 'dotnet --version' in the release definition I discovered that it was only at 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 and so neither dotnet restore or dotnet ef commands were working.

Comment: @TimBunting Edit your release definition > Select a environment > Click Run on agent > Change Deployment queue in the right panel. The version should be 1.0.0.

Comment: You were quite right, I hadnt see in Release definition how to select an agent.